# Как сделать время из даты в формате "чч:мм"?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть время от 7 утра до 19 вечера.
Нужно через дату получить строку вида "чч:мм",но пока в моем варианте если часы или минуты меньше 10, то к примеру, формируется строка "9:40", а нужно "09:40".
Можно ли это сделать не прибегая к лишним проверкам и отдельного добавления нуля в строку?

Мой код:

```
var minutes = 40;
var hours = 9;
var time;
var d1 = new Date(0,0,0,hours,minutes,0,0);
time = d1.getHours()+":"+d1.getMinutes();
console.log(time);
```

Comment: Значение, возвращённое методом getHours(), является целым числом от 0 до 23. Так что без явного форматирования в строку с ведущим нулём никуда не деться.

Comment: `new Date(0,0,0,hours,minutes).toLocaleTimeString('ru').substr(0, 5)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для добавления впереди идущих символов есть [`.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), он принимает целевую длину строки и символ которым нужно заполнить недостающее кол-во символов

только обратите внимание что это метод строки.

```js
var d = new Date(0,0,0,9,40,0,0);
var fmt = t => ("" + t).padStart(2, '0')
var time = fmt(d.getHours()) + ":" + fmt(d.getMinutes());
console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй библиотеку moment.js
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

```
moment(new Date(/* твоя дата тут */), "MM-DD");
```